# Ошибка с register post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здраствуйте у меня есть код,я только начал учить взаимодействие php с  wordpress и сейчас учу register post type.Все вроде бы нормально,но есть проблема.
Обьясню - сайт называется wordpress,создал я с помощью register post type,к примеру машину nissan,
перехожу по  url:wordpress/nissan и все нормально,сайт сам подстраивает запрос под wordpress/car/nissan,
но когда хочу вывести все записи по url wordpress/car,выдает ошибку 404,постоянные ссылки обновлял
и скажите какое значение там должно быть (если это связано с ними)

[[image: код][[image: это на странице wordpress/car/nissan'это на странице wordpress/car]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_post_type_archive_link() - возвращает URL (постоянную ссылку) на страницу архива произвольного типа записи. Можете посмотреть куда ведет эта ссылка и понять какой именно урл

Comment: Спасибо,извини если туплю,но эту функцию вставлять после post type в  function.php ?

Comment: Эта функция возвращает ссылку. Её нужно вставлять в атрибут href у тега <a>. Или просто где то вывести через echo, что бы посмотреть какой адрес у архива этого типа записи

Comment: Спасибо,сработало,меня кинуло на url wordpress/car,все должно быть верно,но увы,ну это уже к другому вопросу,спасибо